# Como tirar linhas pontilhadas da seleção no Firefox, Edge e IE

Tags: css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como consigo tirar essas linhas pontilhadas do menu quando o link é selecionado?
Já tentei usar o `outline:none`, mas funciona apenas no Chrome, já no Firefox, Edge e IE não muda nada.

Comment: Antes de pensar em fazer isso leia um pouco sobre Acessibilidade na Web, pode começar por esse artigo http://www.outlinenone.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente colocar os seletor `:active` e `:focus` no seu link.

```
a:active, a:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado colega, 100% resolvido.